# python: indexing a list as a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there builtin code that indexes a list via an index function? Or do I have to do this:

```
def index(alist, keyExtractor):
    result = dict()
    for item in alist:
        key = keyExtractor(item)
        if key is not None:
            result[key] = item
    return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> import operator
>>> keyExtractor=operator.itemgetter(1) # for demonstration purposes

>>> aList = [('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar'), ('q', 'quux')]
>>> d = {keyExtractor(x):x for x in aList}
>>> if None in d:
      del d[None]
>>> d
{'quux': ('q', 'quux'), 'foo': ('a', 'foo'), 'bar': ('b', 'bar')}
```

Comment: Might want to use `... if keyExtractor(x) is not None}` to allow keys whose "truthiness" is False.

Comment: Fixed! Nicer way to do it anyways, avoid double compute on keyExtractor

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in function, as the use case is relatively rare. If `keyExtractor` always returns a valid key, you can use a shorter [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

```
def index(alist, keyExtractor):
    return {keyExtractor(item):item for item in alist}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{ keyExtractor(item) : item for item in alist }
```

It's available in Python 2.7 and Python 3.

If `keyExtractor` returns `None` you may want to delete the `None` entry afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7:

```
{keyExtractor(i): i for i in alist}
```

For older:

```
dict((keyExtractor(i), i) for i in alist)
```